# Recorrer array desde funcion ajax

Tags: ajax, array

Buenas, tengo una variable sessión llamada api donde tengo almacenadas dos palabras

`echo $_SESSION["api"]['0'];` Esto seria parabra1
`echo $_SESSION["api"]['0'];` Esto sería palabra 2

Esta variable esta en un archivo php y es devuelta a una función ajax en el `success: function(data){`

Desde el archivo php hago `echo $_SESSION["api"];`

Cuando recorro data con un for, lo que necesito es que me muestres las dos palabras: palabra1 y palabra 2, y es resultado que consigo es 'p''a''l''a' etc..

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            alert(data[i])
    }
```

Que estoy haciendo mal? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que retornar cada indice de donde guardas las palabras por separado como un array y luego convertirlo a json y retornarlo:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[0] = $_SESSION["api"];

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Y ahora si podras obtener la palabra completa:

```
//..
.success(function(data){
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
       alert(data[i])
    }
})
```

Y en realidad no se si es un error tipo grafico pero estas guardando tanto el valor de palabra1 como palabra2 en la misma llave api `$_SESSESION["api"]`. Deberias de asignarle una llave diferentes para ambas palabras:

```
$_SESSION["api1"] = "palabra1";
$_SESSION["api2"] = "palabra2";

$arr = array();
$arr[0] = $_SESSION["api1"];
$arr[1] = $_SESSION["api2"];

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias, Perfecto

Comment: Recuerda aceptarla si era la respuestas que esperabas.

Comment: Perdona la duda, como la acepto??

Comment: Dale una miradita al [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y sabras utilizar el sitio completo